# Display clicked image in div javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image, click, fade

I want to display the clicked image into a div.
HTML:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" class="image">
<img src="image2.jpg" class="image">
<div>
    <img id="source">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('img.image').click(function(){
    var source= $(this).attr('src');
    document.getElementById("source")=source;
});
```

Also, the image should change with fade animation effect.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing `src`

```
$('img.image').click(function(){
  var source= $(this).attr('src');
  document.getElementById("source").src=source; // --- Here
});
```

Comment: Van I add fade animation to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following code.

- Providing the same class names to the images to be selected
- Selecting the target image element and then setting the image `src` using the `attr` method.

```js
   $('.imageToBeClicked').click(function(evt){
        $('#source').attr("src", evt.target.src);
    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1" class="imageToBeClicked"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image2" class="imageToBeClicked"/>
    <div>
        <img id="source">
    </div>
```